# IIS 7: different start page for different domains in the same web server

Tags: iis-7, web, domains

I want to host one web application in IIS. But the situation is that we need to provide two domain names which will be pointing to two different start pages for the same application.   Currently we have one domain name and one start page for users.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you might be looking for [this information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on how to configure IIS7 to host multiple sites by handling headers properly.